# How to highlight selected link in panel of jquery mobile?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, selecteditem

I'm have a jquery mobile page with navigation menu in a sliding panel. It's working quite well, but want to improve the navigation by highlighting the selected link in the navigation.

Usually i would use a class like ".selected", etc.

Why it doesn't work here?

```
$('#navlist a').click(function() {
    $('#navlist a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5TDg9/ptuX7/

Answer (score 1):

its probably having some conflict.
you can just use `!important`

http://jsfiddle.net/ptuX7/3/

```
.selected { color: red !important; }
```